# Manipulate data.table to expand Date

Tags: r, date, data.table, data-manipulation

Suppose I have this data.table:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(Event = c("P_2800 Back","Holiday_PRE","Holiday","Holiday_POST","P_100 Back","Holiday_PRE","Holiday","Holiday_POST", "P_100 Back"), Event_From=c("25/03/2010","11/04/2010","12/04/2010" ,"15/04/2010","02/05/2010", "11/04/2011","12/04/2011" ,"15/04/2011","02/05/2011"), Event_Pre=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1), Event_Post=c(NA, NA, NA,NA,2, NA, NA,NA,2), Event_To=c("25/03/2010","11/04/2010","14/04/2010" ,"15/04/2010","02/05/2010","11/04/2011","14/04/2011" ,"15/04/2011","02/05/2011"), Holiday=c(F,F,T,F,F,F,T,F,F))
```

Return,

```
          Event Event_From Event_Pre Event_Post   Event_To Holiday
1:  P_2800 Back 25/03/2010         NA        NA 25/03/2010   FALSE
2:  Holiday_PRE 11/04/2010         NA        NA 11/04/2010   FALSE
3:      Holiday 12/04/2010         NA        NA 14/04/2010    TRUE
4: Holiday_POST 15/04/2010         NA        NA 15/04/2010   FALSE
5:   P_100 Back 02/05/2010          1         2 02/05/2010   FALSE
6:  Holiday_PRE 11/04/2011         NA        NA 11/04/2011   FALSE
7:      Holiday 12/04/2011         NA        NA 14/04/2011    TRUE
8: Holiday_POST 15/04/2011         NA        NA 15/04/2011   FALSE
9:   P_100 Back 02/05/2011          1         2 02/05/2011   FALSE
```

I would like to expand the original date column to include

1. the dates between the ones in column `Event_From`  and `Event_To`.
2. *n* dates before the date in column `Event_From` and *m* dates after `Event_To` where *n* is the value in column `Event_Pre` and *m* in `Event_Post` (in this example, for the event P_100 Back, the result should be the dates between 01/05/2010 and 04/05/2010)

**The final result should be as follows:**

```
Event             Date          Holiday
P_2800 Back       25/03/2010    FALSE
Holiday_PRE       11/04/2010    FALSE
Holiday           12/04/2010    TRUE
Holiday           13/04/2010    TRUE
Holiday           14/04/2010    TRUE
Holiday_POST      15/04/2010    FALSE
P_100 Back        01/05/2010    FALSE
P_100 Back        02/05/2010    FALSE
P_100 Back        03/05/2010    FALSE
P_100 Back        04/05/2010    FALSE
Holiday_PRE       11/04/2011    FALSE
Holiday           12/04/2011    TRUE
Holiday           13/04/2011    TRUE
Holiday           14/04/2011    TRUE
Holiday_POST      15/04/2011    FALSE
P_100 Back        01/05/2011    FALSE
P_100 Back        02/05/2011    FALSE
P_100 Back        03/05/2011    FALSE
P_100 Back        04/05/2011    FALSE
```

Could you please give me suggestions about manipulating this data.table ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Let's get rid of those pesky NA's
data[is.na(Event_Post), Event_Post := 0]
data[is.na(Event_Pre), Event_Pre := 0]

# Not much left, construct the final result
data[, list(Date = seq(as.Date(Event_From, format="%d/%m/%Y") - Event_Post,
                       as.Date(Event_To, format="%d/%m/%Y") + Event_Pre,
                       by = 1),
            Holiday),
       by = list(Event, Event_From)][, !"Event_From"]
#           Event       Date Holiday
# 1:  P_2800 Back 2010-03-25   FALSE
# 2:  Holiday_PRE 2010-04-11   FALSE
# 3:      Holiday 2010-04-12    TRUE
# 4:      Holiday 2010-04-13    TRUE
# 5:      Holiday 2010-04-14    TRUE
# 6: Holiday_POST 2010-04-15   FALSE
# 7:   P_100 Back 2010-04-30   FALSE
# 8:   P_100 Back 2010-05-01   FALSE
# 9:   P_100 Back 2010-05-02   FALSE
#10:   P_100 Back 2010-05-03   FALSE
#11:  Holiday_PRE 2011-04-11   FALSE
#12:      Holiday 2011-04-12    TRUE
#13:      Holiday 2011-04-13    TRUE
#14:      Holiday 2011-04-14    TRUE
#15: Holiday_POST 2011-04-15   FALSE
#16:   P_100 Back 2011-04-30   FALSE
#17:   P_100 Back 2011-05-01   FALSE
#18:   P_100 Back 2011-05-02   FALSE
#19:   P_100 Back 2011-05-03   FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for your work, but if we have duplicate events, for example the same holiday that is in 2011, the code generate error below: `Error in seq.Date(as.Date(Event_From, format = "%d/%m/%Y") - Event_Post,  : 
  'from' must be of length 1`.  I have revised the OP to reflect this problem

Comment: @newbie the change is trivial if you understand what's going on above. You simply should group by `list(Event, Event_From)` instead of simply `Event` - see edit